# How to measure power consumption of a lot of circuits?

Tags: current-measurement, hall-effect, toroid

Our house has a lot of electrical circuits/breakers and I have thought about how nice it would be to be able to monitor current consumption for each of them in parallel. Of course one can buy meters for the distribution enclosure, but firstly they are not cheap if I want to have ~60 pieces of them, and secondly that many would consume a lot of space inside the enclosure, let alone consume some power of their own for their supply/display etc.

So I thought about placing some kind of current clamp around each line wire. Probably a simple toroidal coil would do, because the wires to probe could be threaded through them, no clamping feature necessary. Other possibility would be hall sensors, but I don't know if they can be used at 50 Hz.

Does that sound reasonable (aside from the ramifications of how to multiplex the signals to a controller board, and how to take power factor into account)? What problems will I encounter? Are there even similar existing solutions for such applications?

Comment: Sounds pretty reasonable; this is what any engineer would do; the actual current transformer shouldn't be too expensive (especially if you're talking a DIY hack job). However, there are probably implications for safety and for the building code (which is about safety). No extra electrical problems

Comment: This kind of product already exists. Search "smart home energy monitor" on eCommerce sites. Some only monitor the whole house draw, but others have current transformers for each branch circuit. You can also find replacement circuit breakers with built-in current sensors, which would result in a very neat installation, but be prepared to spend $$$ for that.

Comment: Search term: "kill-a-watt".  There may be competitors by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to monitor the power of the entire house, you can use clamp-on or split-CT sensors, one on each main phase.

But if you want to measure each circuit individually, you may be able to attach a linear Hall-effect sensor to each circuit. You can get them with a toroidal flux concentrator, and you can even make your own using powdered iron toroids and cutting a slot for the sensor (in a 3 wire TO-92 package), but these involve removing the wires, which is inconvenient and may be unsafe.

However, you might also be able to glue these sensors to the wires. Since they actually measure magnetic fields, they will be sensitive to orientation with respect to other current-carrying wires, as well as the earth's magnetic field. And you will also need to calibrate them.

Here is a commercially available small toroidal Hall effect current sensor:

[image: Hall effect current sensor]

And here is a powdered iron core in which I cut a gap for a TO-92 sensor:

[image: Homemade current sensor]

That gave about 16 mV/A, but exhibited a few mV of hysteresis due to the magnetic core. It will probably work better on AC.

I also wrapped three turns of #18 AWG magnet wire around one of the DRV5053 sensors, and I got the following results (and no hysteresis):

0.00  1.0146

-1.00  0.9983  16.3 mV/A

-2.00  0.9826  16.0 mV/A

-3.00  0.9669  15.9 mV/A

-4.00  0.9509  15.9 mV/A

-5.00  0.9354  15.8 mV/A

0.00  1.0152

1.00  1.0313  16.1 mV/A

2.00  1.0471  15.9 mV/A

3.00  1.0626  15.8 mV/A

4.00  1.0786  15.8 mV/A

5.00  1.0949  15.9 mV/A​

Gluing the sensor to a single conductor will probably give 5-10 mV/A.

Comment: Nice, looks just like what I have been looking for. However, I am not so familiar with transformers and core materials. Aren't the hysteresis and losses going to distort 50 Hz AC signals so much that it will be difficult to do a calibration algorithm them in the controller?

Comment: Oh, wait, the product from the first picture is end-of-life unfortunately. I have looked into alternatives, but they are almost obscenely expensive (>50 €). Looks like I'll end up with a DIY solution - 50 €/unit seems like a good wage rate for cutting a gap into ~60 toroids with my angle grinder... ^^

Comment: After reading a bit, I have become aware that powder iron is just for the purpose reducing eddy current losses.

Comment: Search for powdered iron toroids on eBay. Also try Surplus Sales of Nebraska. I was able to cut the gap with a small hacksaw, but a Dremel with abrasive disk also works. But first try gluing one of the Hall sensors onto a length of wire to see what kind of output you get. Even 5 mV/A is workable, and it's good to be able to avoid hysteresis. The version I used has 45 mV/T, but you can get 73 mV/T. These can sense the earth's magnetic field (30-65 uT).